# Uber universal deep link in mailing not working

Tags: html, email, deep-linking, uber-api

I want to send an email that with a button opens the uber app and gives them the dropoff location.

The issue here is that when I put the universal deep link from uber in a  element the link redirects to the web login and a pop up appears saying if you want to open the Uber App and if you say yes the App Opens without the parameters I set in the link (the parameters where dropoff and the user's pickup position).

Does anyone have this issue? Any tips or suggestions?

The link is:

https://m.uber.com/ul?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=19.4295176&dropoff[longitude]=-99.1689479&dropoff[nickname]=Koku&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Rio%20Lerma%2094B&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d

PS. I have read about the limitations of universal deep links, but this thing does not work properly (not in IOS and not in android).

Comment: I just created a deeplink to the location you have in your deeplink: `https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&pickup=my_location&dropoff[nickname]=Koku&dropoff[formatted_address]=Calle%20R%C3%ADo%20Lerma%2094B%2C%20Cuauht%C3%A9moc%2C%20Mexico%20City%2C%20Mexico&dropoff[latitude]=19.429668&dropoff[longitude]=-99.166141`. This deeplink works for me. Can you try it with your own client_id? Also, the product_id can only be specified if the pickup location is known. Without a pickup location, it's unclear which products might be available at the user's location.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about the product ID. And I added my client ID, but the link still doesn't work when I insert it on the mailing, still opens the web login even if the app is installed...

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that. What Uber version do you use? How do you open the deeplink (which browser)? Which OS (Android/iOS version)? Did you try killing the Uber app to force a fresh start?